# PyDev: Can't compile after accidentally naming file after Python io.py

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, pydev

So I without thinking stupidly named a file io.py in my working directory. When I tried to compile I got a traceback error. Having realised what I'd done I renamed my file and updated references to it but I still get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tom\workspace\Converter\get_file.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scipy import complex_
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 185, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from numpy.testing import Tester
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .utils import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tempfile import mkdtemp
  File "C:\Python27\lib\tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "C:\Users\Tom\workspace\Converter\io.py", line 1, in <module>
    """The io module provides the Python interfaces to stream handling. The
  File "C:\Users\Tom\workspace\Converter\get_file.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scipy import complex_
ImportError: cannot import name complex_
```

I have restarted PyDev to no avail. I have refreshed the interpreter to no avail.

I have followed the instructions found in [this Python issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue22967) but that command returns the correct result on my machine.

Is tempfile.py a temporary file I can remove to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Stupidly simple but maybe worth leaving here for other newbies who fall into the same trap.

PyDev compiles the code into *.pyc files. When you update the references and rename the files these aren't immediately recompiled. Deleting the io.pyc file I had allowed compilation too run properly.

I found some [more info on common pitfalls](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html) too.

Comment: As a note, in PyDev you can right-click a folder and select PyDev > Remove *.pyc/*.pyo, to remove those folders (and yes, you should probably try not to shadow Python top-level modules as other things may rely on those).